# Language neutral and small in size serialization for java objects

Tags: java, serialization, json-deserialization, json-serialization

I want to migrate an application which currently uses java serialization to a one which is language neutral like JSON with polymorphic serialization/deserialization the problem is my objects are very large and that is causing to generate large JSON data which I don't want.

Example -
An object serialised through java would create a file of around 7 MB. For the same JSON file will be of 200 MB.

P.S - I am currently using Jackson for JSON as it has a good support for polymorphic serialization/deserialization with annotations.
I have tried Smile by Jackson. It is reducing size but not that much

Can someone advice a better language neutral serialization approach which will produce very less data as java does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Requests for libraries, tools and other off-site resources is explicitly off-topic. That said, I like [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/index.html#flatbuffers_overview).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how does flatbuffers or protobufs support polymorphic serialization/deserialization?, like jackson does using annotation actually I don't have an idea about that and could not find any documents related to it